# Reduce number of instance methods

Tags: ruby

I am modelling a report as a class and each column value as an accessor. Each value in the report needs to be accessed from the database. But this makes the class look quite fat and RubyMine warns me of too many methods in class.

```
class Report

attr_accessor :name, :col1, :col2, :col3 .... :col15

def col1
 db.find({x: 1})['some_var']
end

def col2
 db.find({y: 4})['some_other_var']
end

and so forth for each attribute...

end
```

Since each getter is essentially single line that makes call to database, is there a simpler way to declare these vars without being in a method?

I don't want to set these in the initialize method as these reports will be subclassed and child reports will not have all/some of these attributes.

Comment: have you considered using [ActiveRecord](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activerecord) since it will handle most of the complexities of dealing with databases including all the getter setters by default?

Comment: @lacostenycoder - The db calls are for Mongo so can't use AR. I could use MongoId but I am not using that at present. The reports are quite complicated and data changes every year with historic data still available in the app so I will still end up writing custom getters for most of it

Comment: Having said that this question is quite generic. Database calls aside imagine each of these methods has custom code to generate data

Comment: Is there any pattern logic to the method's definition or is it arbitrary?

Comment: Why don't you want to use a method? It seems quite natural here: `def lookup(a, b) db.find(a)[b] end`? (Aside: `find({x: 1})` and be written `find(x: 1)`.)

Comment: Thanks @CarySwoveland. Absolutely no issues using the methods. Only because I end up having 20 something methods in the class I was wondering if there's a better approach

Comment: Why `20+` methods? The method I suggested replaces `col1`, `col2` and all others having the same structure (returning `db.find(a)[b]`).

Answer (score 1):

You can use meta-programming to create attr_accessor like methods on the fly.

For Example:

```
class Report
  def initialize(attributes)
    attributes.each do |attribute|
      define_singleton_method :"#{attribute}" do |hash_param, string_param|
        db.find(hash_param)[string_param]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Then you can create new report object and pass attribute names as follow:

```
r = Report.new(["n","m"])
```

Now you can call `n` and `m` methods on the `r` object

```
r.m({val1: "val1"}, "val2")
r.n({val2: "val1"}, "val2")
```

Comment: define_singleton_method define a method on the class not on the instance.

Comment: Not true! every object also has a somewhat hidden singleton class.
This is what allows methods to be defined on individual objects.
In my above example the methods `m` and `n` will be defined on the object `Report.new(["n","m"])`

Answer (score 0):

@Rahul based on answer to my question, the only advice I can give here then is to use best OOP design principles. Subclass and modularize where possible as well as using ruby meta-programming.  If you need the methods, they have to be written somewhere.  But if you only need getters, consider `attr_reader` instead, unless you'll need setters too.

If you can get the column names you can use dynamic method definition with something like this assuming `db` is magically defined somewhere you have not made clear, we'll assume it's a connection to the database.

```
class Report

  db.column_names.each do |col|
    define_method(col.to_sym) { db.find(options={}) }
  end

end
```

If you just want RubyMine to stop nagging you, I assume it's using rubocop and you can see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37309321/how-do-i-suppress-rubocop-conventions#40259471) for how to override rules.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/2017.1/rubocop.html

or

https://github.com/rubocop-hq/rubocop

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately there's no common similarities between these methods other than the fact that they find record in Mongo based on filters and then access one or more attributes of that record. But I am using methods like I said above, I just wanted to know if there was a better way to do this. I looked at a developers code for this in C# and because they can define all these as variables instead of methods outside initialize I was looking for similar solution in Ruby

Comment: In ruby you can define instance variables inside `def initialize` method but still not sure if this is what you want / need.